# UIImageview not showing image in whole app in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, xcode6

I am facing one serious issue in my app regarding `UIImageview`. It's not displaying images if i set from using `UIImageView` in xib but if i set it through code then it's getting displayed. And this issue is coming in `Xcode 5.1.1` or above version of `Xcode` and in device. In simulator it's displaying all images perfectly.

Please help me solving this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what is you image name format?

Comment: It's a png image. Name is usernameselbg.png

Comment: i am working with xcode6.1 i did not get this type of issue. may be there is you image format issue

Comment: If i am printing uiimageview then it's alpha is 0 while in xib it's 1. I am setting it's alpha through coding though it's becoming 0.

Comment: issue is in to your coding not in xcode if imageview alpha is 0 then how that will be displying.?

Comment: May be your problem happen for your image. For checking it try with other images.

Comment: @ShahPaneri please have a look on my answer

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help

if your image is shown in simulator(in all the condition through .xib or programmatically)  and not in device , it might due to of case-sensitiveness

```
iPhone OS uses a case-sensitive file system, unlike the Simulator which uses a case-insensitive file system by default
```

for info:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1697/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem and what I did is just deleted the `UIImageview` and reconfigured it and it worked. I think this is the problem with `XCode new versions`.

Comment: No. It's not working. Even i have taken new xib and in that i have taken uiimageview. Though my image is not getting displayed!!

Comment: Ensure that you have all your constraints set so that the UIImageView is actually visible. You can also set the view's background color to make sure its actually on-screen.

Comment: @PatrickTNelson : If i am printing uiimageview then it's alpha is 0 while in xib it's 1. I am setting it's alpha through coding though it's becoming 0.

Comment: @PatrickTNelson : And if i am giving color to `UIImageView` instead setting image though it's not getting displayed.

Comment: Kindly post the code here so that we can correct it.

Comment: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    NSLog(@"before imgUserNmBg frm = %@",imgUserNmBg);
    
    imgUserNmBg.hidden = NO;
    imgUserNmBg.alpha = 1.0;
    imgUserNmBg.opaque = YES;
    
    NSLog(@"after imgUserNmBg frm = %@",imgUserNmBg); }

Comment: Output: after imgUserNmBg frm = <UIImageView: 0x135d17940; frame = (20 107; 285 45); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17022b040>>

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem/bug with Auto Layout constraints in iOS 7. If you remove the constraints on the UIView, it works no problem. You can set frames programmatically if you need to.

Comment: I am not using auto layout in any view.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
[youImageView setOpacity:1];
```

Actually "opacity" means "value of alpha-channel" of your UIView. When a view is fully opaque this means its alpha = 1, when a view is fully transparent (non-opaque) its alpha = 0.

As about properties of CALayer and UIView in Cocoa, they provide the same functionality.